# What is the best way to break my Backbone and Marionette app into modules?

Tags: backbone.js, gruntjs, marionette

I purchased the PDF book on getting started with Marionette.js, and they show how to use Marionette modules.  However, this is deprecated in the next major release.

What is the best, or most simple tool, to allow me to break my project up into modules?  This app is getting pretty big, and is at the point where it's a pain to make changes.

Is Grunt what I want?  I hear about Browserify as well, but I really want to start simple.  If anyone has any advice, or can point me to a good tutorial, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Marionette Wires](https://github.com/thejameskyle/marionette-wires) is a great starting point for structuring large Marionette applications. It uses browserify and Babelify to allow ES6 imports and features. It is an opinionated set of tools based on [Backbone.Routing](https://github.com/thejameskyle/backbone-routing) for pages and [Backbone.Service](https://github.com/thejameskyle/backbone.service) or singleton objects as the entry point for reusable components.

We have written our own library [Orchestra](https://github.com/BedeGaming/orchestra) on top of Backbone/Marionette which takes a lot of the pain out of setting up a new Marionette application and provides a proven set of dependencies which work well together. We are currently in the process of releasing a new set of features for Orchestra including isomorphic server side rendering and attaching to an existing DOM, a CLI tool to set up a new application and perform common tasks like setting up a new component, and a Handlebars to iDOM compiler for faster re-rendering (proven faster than React). This will all be in our next major release so watch this space!

Comment: There is a great community behind Marionette and it's my framework of choice for most large projects. Check out the Gitter channel for news, also for help and advice from the community - https://gitter.im/marionettejs/backbone.marionette